# how to set url for ajax page when using it in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, path

In jQuery ajax function, you have to point out the url of Ajax page, for local development and remote server environment, the url is different. I think we should use a variable to store root path and then use it to set url. I use following line to get `rootpath` in backend.

```
rootpath=page.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

and pass the `rootpath` value to the frontend.

```
$.ajax({
    url:rootpath+'/AjaxPages/....',
    ....
```

But I found that in local development machine, it turns out that `rootpath='/UI'` (I use UI folder for my website files) but in server `rootpth='/'` So `url:rootpath+'/AjaxPages/....'` does not work here, I have to erase one slash to make it as `url:rootpath+'AjaxPages/....'`

How do you guys set the ajax page path?

Comment: Is it running in a virtual directory or something some where? I ask because I'm wondering if just using a relative path from the root of the application would work.

Comment: isn't it then just possible to call the page using a relative path from the root of the application? for example if your www.site.com/ajaxpages/yourpage.html. The ajax URL could simply be /ajaxpages/yourpage.html. It wouldn't matter what the actual domain name is